# checking if a substring of length 5 is in another string (refactored)

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I'm trying to check if string `b` contains any 5-character substring `a`.

This works, but is a little messy:

```
var a = "1eabcde";
var b = "12abcde12fg";

    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(var j=i;j<a.length-i;j++){
            if(a.charAt(j) == b.charAt(i) && a.charAt(j+1) == b.charAt(i+1) && a.charAt(j+2) == b.charAt(i+2) && a.charAt(j+3) == b.charAt(i+3) && a.charAt(j+4) == b.charAt(i+4)){
                alert("ya");
             }                              
         }
     }
```

Are there any other cleaner options?

Comment: I'm a little confused, is the result supposed to be if 1, e, a, b, c, d, e is in the second string regardless of order?

Comment: sorry its supposed to be if the 5 characters are present in the same order, let me edit*

Comment: You mean 'if string a' not b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var a = "1eabcde";
var b = "12abcde12fg";

for (var i = 0; i <= a.length - 5; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a.substring(i, i + 5)) >= 0) {
        alert("ya");
    }
}
```

(You could use `a.substr(i, 5)` instead of `a.substring(i, i + 5)`. Those two calls behave identically.)

Note that if you loop from `0` to `a.length` (as in your original code), then all suffixes of `a` of length 5 or less will be searched for in `b`.

In one respect, this code does not behave the same as your original: it will alert only once for each matching substring of `a`, regardless of how many times that particular substring may occur in `b`. Thus, if `a = 'abcde'` and `b = '01abcde23abcde45`, your original code would pop up two alerts (one for each occurrence of `'abcde'`), whereas the above will only alert once. If you want the original behavior, change the `if` to a `while` like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= a.length - 5; i++) {
    var j = -1;
    while ((j = b.substring(j+1).indexOf(a.substr(i, 5))) >= 0) {
        alert("ya");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **the cleanest** approach :

```js
var a = "1eabcde";
var b = "12abcde12fg";

for (var i = 0; i <= a.length - 5; i++) {
    if(b.indexOf(a.substr(i, 5)) > -1) {
        alert("ya");
    }
}
```

Comment: need to match 5 characters not one

Comment: @codemonkey : Do 5 characters need to be matched individually or as a whole? What [**`b.indexOf(a) !== -1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) does, is check if `a` is a substring of `b`.

Comment: OP's original code (excluding end effects) looks for any five consecutive characters of `a` in `b`.

Comment: they need to match as a whole so for example if b contains 'abcd' in order

Comment: @codemonkey : Then `b.indexOf(a) !== -1` is exactly what you're looking for!

Comment: No, because `b.indexOf(a)` will only find occurrences of all of `a`. OP wants to search for every 5-character substring of `a`.

Comment: @codemonkey : I misunderstood the question. Anyway, see the latest version for **the cleanest** approach to solve your problem!